# Is there a graph data structure in solidity?

Tags: solidity, struct, graphs

I am trying to achieve a file lineage information Dapp and I need a graph kind of data structure for that. I know I can always write one but is there a ready to use data structure that is efficient enough?

Comment: Not as part of the Solidity language. Perhaps there's an open-source implementation somewhere, which has been verified by the community, so you can take it as an off-the-shelf product ready for use.

Comment: I have searched for it but was unsuccessful in finding one. Maybe if someone knows of one it would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't sound like you did a thorough work (or even a minimal effort) on that one. I googled "solidity graph data structure" and immediately bumped into [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/78334/16043), written by the highest-ranked user on this website. Why don't you start off with that?

Comment: lol! must have missed my eyes! Thanks though!!!!

Comment: If you look at the comment-thread on that answer, then you'll even find a link to an already implemented library by the same dude.