# Graph traversals on Ethereum, at scale

Tags: solidity, contract-design, design-patterns, graphs

I read the [Efficient Solidity storage pattern for a directional weighted graph](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78333/efficient-solidity-storage-pattern-for-a-directional-weighted-graph) thread, but that deals with storing graphs. I'm interested in techniques for how to **traverse** graphs in Solidity, at scale.

Consider the following data pattern, which uses Rob Hitchens' [UnorderedKeySet](https://github.com/rob-Hitchens/UnorderedKeySet) library to build a table-like database with rows and keys:

```
contract GraphTraversal {
    using HitchensUnorderedAddressSetLib for HitchensUnorderedAddressSetLib.Set;
    using HitchensUnorderedKeySetLib for HitchensUnorderedKeySetLib.Set;

    struct User {
        uint256 balance;
        uint256[] incomingStreamIds;
        mapping(uint256 => uint256) incomingStreamIdPointers; /* left is stream is row in table */
        uint256[] outgoingStreamIds;
        mapping(uint256 => uint256) outgoingStreamIdPointers; /* left is stream id, right is row in table */
    }

    mapping(address => User) public users;
    HitchensUnorderedAddressSetLib.Set userSet;

    struct Stream {
        uint256 interval;
        uint256 paymentRate;
        address sender; /* key for a User struct */
        address recipient; /* key for a User struct */
        uint256 startTime;
        uint256 stopTime;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => Stream) public streams;
    HitchensUnorderedKeySetLib.Set streamSet;
}
```

---

Highlights:

- Each user references two sets, incoming and outgoing streams, which are both capped in length - the contract enforces an upper limit on how many incoming and outgoing streams can be created
- Each stream references two users, a sender and a recipient

The above is a **two-to-many** data relationship between users and streams. We define streams as financial agreements whereby the sender pays the recipient a specific amount of money once every so often.

---

Now, what I want to achieve:

- Have a `rebalance` function that iterates over all incoming and outgoing streams that refer to a user
- Recursively call `rebalance` for every sender of an incoming stream and every recipient of an outgoing stream - essentially a [depth-first search (DFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)
- If at any stage during the function call, a user is under-collateralised (the payment amount required by the the streams exceeds his current balance), delete the current stream and all streams that succeed it
- At the end of the `rebalance` function, update each user's `balance` property by adding up all the income provided by the incoming streams and subtracting all payments made to outgoing streams

---

Obviously, this is not feasible on Ethereum mainnet (at scale). I'd hit the block gas limit with relatively few users and streams.

How could something like this be implemented? Maybe SNARKs or optimistic rollups that do the graph traversal off-chain and post a succinct proof on mainnet afterward?

For a pseudocode implementation of the `rebalance` function, [see this gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/PaulRBerg/f8473d9de0f2ea398612ee75487e0487).

Answer (score 3):

You could require streamers to overcollateralize, with those that fail to stay overcollateralized being liquidated. With that you can take a lazy update approach, where self-interested actors update the smart contracts in a patchwork pattern.

So imagine for example that all streams are required to post collateral for at least 3 hours of streaming. When a stream is lawfully closed, for example as an agreement between streamer and streamed, the streamer gets the 3 hours of collateral back.

A liquidation process could be started by anyone on anyone that has less than 3 hours of collateral to cover their streams. If successful the liquidator gets the collateral, but also the streams. Gets the whole account.

The liquidator now needs to top up the collateral pool, and possibly close the outgoing streams. Think of it as a forced acquisition of a company. If done properly, it will result in a net profit for the liquidator.

The state of any streamer can be calculated off-chain with the smart contracts not fully updated. For a liquidation to happen, the smart contracts need to be in a state where the undercollateralization can be verified, though. Therefore, the liquidators can maintain their own off-chain copy of the state, looking for liquidation opportunities. When they find one, they can update the bare minimum to prove that the liquidation is valid.

Apart from that, to keep the smart contracts as updated as possible, streamer updating can be bundled into other transactions, same as `Pot.sol` forces anyone whating to know the `chi` to update it to the current `now`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to iterate over all streams each time?

You could have a time function that tells you the outgoing total and incoming totals per second, it would be based on just one variable per user which gets updated each time the streams are modified. You could know if an user is undercolaterallized with a simple operation.

Have a look at how `Pot.sol` from MakerDAO and `ERC20DividendableEth.sol` from HQ20 work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This provides a partial solution for the conundrum. I still need to compute the single variable for every single user in a "stream chain" - imagine user A streaming money to user B, B streaming to C, and so on and so forth. The only way to make it work, at scale, would be to enforce a limit on how long a path in the graph can become, but this makes for a fragile implementation and a terrible UX for end-users.

Comment: Is it your concern that if A stops streaming might cause B to stop streaming and so on to the end of the line, so that you have to recalculate an unbounded quantity of users to see who is insolvent?

Comment: Precisely. But the issue occurs not only when somebody stops streaming - any state update would have to calculate a potentially unbound chain of users. If user no. 100 depends on user no.10 for his income, stream balances have to be computed sequentially for user no. 11, no. 12, etc.